# rdtsc delta to nanosecond conversion

Tags: linux, cpu, cpu-architecture, latency, rdtsc

Recently, I have been trying to run some performance anlaysis on my program.
I want to measure the latency of some functions in cpu ticks and later convert the delta to nanosecond.
(I intentionally am not using std::chrono::system_clock::now for direct nanosecond mesaure, so let's set that discussion aside.)

In order to get the CPU frequency, (Intel(R) Core(TM) i9-10980XE), I run get_tsc_freq_arch(). And it shows 3GHz - which is the same number I see from lscpu.
However, the machine is actually running overclocked, which is at ~5GHz.

In this case, is it right to assume that each tick is 1/3G? or 1/5G?
My intuition says 1/5G, but I was told to use 1/3G and I'd like to learn the reason.

Always many thanks to stackoverflow gurus!

Comment: The TSC runs at a fixed "reference" frequency, regardless of the core clock being at idle or max turbo.  The TSC frequency is often somewhat near the "sticker" frequency (max non-turbo), or the TDP-up frequency. See [How to get the CPU cycle count in x86\_64 from C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13772567) for details; it has a whole section *"rdtsc counts reference cycles, not CPU core clock cycles"*

Comment: You can measure it yourself by putting a sleep(1) in between your rdtsc measurements and printing the difference.